# Редирект на default страницу

Tags: symfony4

Разбираюсь с симфони и хотел сделать так, чтобы при отсутствии параметра он автоматически подставлялся.

```
class LuckyController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/number/{page}", name="lucky_number", defaults={"page"="1"})
     */
    public function number($page)
    {
        return $this->render('lucky/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Если мы перейдем по `http://localhost/number` то редиректа не произойдет, а я бы хотел, чтобы он автоматически редиректил на `http://localhost/number/1` при отсутвии параметра `page`. Возможно ли такое сделать без плясок с написанием кастомных роутов?

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то поможет, то вот как я решил вопрос

```
class LuckyController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/number")
     * @Route("/number/{page}", name="lucky_number")
     */
    public function number($page = null)
    {
        if ($page === null) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('lucky_number', ['page' => 1]);
        }
        return $this->render('lucky/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```